# API Gateway for gRpc services

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, netflix-zuul, api-gateway, grpc-java

I am using grpc http protocol but i want to pass all grpc calls through a gateway to centerlize the calls. I am using Zuul proxy gateway in spring boot application. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked zuul doesn't support http/2 which gRPC needs.